# angularjs - ui.router sibling states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `bootstrap` with `angularjs` (and `ui-router` for routing).
I have a `navbar` where each tab click need to view another nested `navbar` in it. 
The nested `navbar` is a ui-view (should I do it differently?).
The problem is that when I click one **li** in the main navbar, all of the four nested navbar views are shown.

```
div(ng-controller='MyCtrl')
h1 Header
ul.nav.nav-tabs(role="tablist")
    li.active(role="presentation")
        a(ui-sref='first_nested_state') General
        div(ui-view)
    li.active.navbar-padding-left(role="presentation")
        a(ui-sref='second_nested_state') User
        div(ui-view)
    li.active.navbar-padding-left(role="presentation")
        a(ui-sref='third_nested_state') User
        div(ui-view)
    li.active.navbar-padding-left(role="presentation")
        a(ui-sref='fourth_nested_state') User
        div(ui-view)
```

And here is one nested navbar (they all look the same, except for the names):

```
div(ui-view)
ul.nav.nav-tabs(role="tablist", color="red")
  li.active(role="presentation")
     a(ng-href='#') A
  li.active(role="presentation")
     a(ng-href='#') B
  li.active(role="presentation")
     a(ng-href='#') C
```

And my state configuration:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('main_nav_bar', {
          url: '/main_nav_bar',
          templateUrl: 'main_nav_bar.html'
      })
    .state('first_nested_navbar', {
        parent: 'main_nav_bar',
        url: '/first_nested_navbar',
        templateUrl: 'first_nested_navbar.html'
      })
    .state('second_nested_navbar', {
        parent: 'mainNavBar',
        url: '/second_nested_navbar',
        templateUrl: 'second_nested_navbar.html'
      })
```

I'm using `coffeescript` and `jade` as well.

Comment: just found what jade is. cool thing, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here *("...when I click one `<li>`...all of the four nested navbar views are shown...")* is related to repeated definition **`div(ui-view)`**

That means, that in the page DOM contains 4 `<div ui-view></div>`. All of them are used as a target for selected content. That's why we can see it rendered four times.

Solution should be in named views:

see: **[Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)**

In our case, we should use this HTML definition

```
li.active(role="presentation")
    a(ui-sref='first_nested_state') General
    div(ui-view="first") // give it name "first"
li.active.navbar-padding-left(role="presentation")
    a(ui-sref='second_nested_state') User
    div(ui-view="second") // give it name "second"
...
```

And use explicit views definitions of our states:

```
...
.state('first_nested_navbar', {
    parent: 'main_nav_bar',
    url: '/first_nested_navbar',
    views : {
      'first' : {   // now we explicitly inject into anchor/target "first"
        templateUrl: 'first_nested_navbar.html'
      },
    }
  })
.state('second_nested_navbar', {
    parent: 'mainNavBar',
    url: '/second_nested_navbar',
    views : {
      'second' : { // here we target the ui-view="second"
        templateUrl: 'second_nested_navbar.html'
      },
    }
  })
```

Check the really well documented example [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names), see the below snippet from that source:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
    // This will get automatically plugged into the unnamed ui-view 
    // of the parent state template. Since this is a top level state, 
    // its parent state template is index.html.
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'   
  })
  .state('contacts.detail', {
    views: {
        ////////////////////////////////////
        // Relative Targeting             //
        // Targets parent state ui-view's //
        ////////////////////////////////////

        // Relatively targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
        // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
        "detail" : { },            

        // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
        // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
        "" : { }, 

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Absolute Targeting using '@'                      //
        // Targets any view within this state or an ancestor //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Absolutely targets the 'info' view in this state, 'contacts.detail'.
        // <div ui-view='info'/> within contacts.detail.html
        "info@contacts.detail" : { }

        // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in the 'contacts' state.
        // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
        "detail@contacts" : { }
```

Comment: Well explained. Solved. Thanks !

Comment: Great to see that :) enjoy awesome ui-router :)